# Connection between Eulerian numbers and number of elements in set of uniform variables greater than the mean?

Tags: combinatorics, uniform-distribution, eulerian-numbers

I was recently investigating the following question: Given $n$ independent $\text{Unif(0, 1)}$ variables $U_1,\ldots,U_n$, let $m$ be the number of elements in $[U_1,\ldots,U_n]$ that are greater than the mean $\frac{U_1+\ldots+U_n}{n}$. What is the distribution of $m$ given $n$? For example, if $U_1,U_2,U_3,U_4=0.2,0.7,0.8,0.9$, then the mean is $0.65$ and $U_2,U_3,U_4$ are greater than the mean, so $m=3$. Running lots of simulations in Python, it appears that the probability of having $m$ elements greater than the mean in $n$ independent $\text{Unif(0, 1)}$ variables is

$$P(m|n)=\frac{A(n-1,m-1)}{(n-1)!}$$

Where $A(n-1,m-1)$ is the Eulerian number equal to the number of permutations of $(1,\ldots,n-1)$ with $m-1$ ascents. More information about the Eulerian numbers can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number and https://oeis.org/A008292

Does anyone know of an existing proof relating the Eulerian numbers to number of uniform variables above the mean? The closest thing I could find is a proof that $P(k-1\leq\sum\limits_{i=1}^n U_i \leq k)=\frac{A(n,k)}{n!}$, in the following article: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316597928326